# Adding status to a facebook page

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to post a message to the user’s Facebook wall using Spring-social-facebook api. Below is my code. I think it's not my code error and some of the jars I needed to include may not be there. Can anyone tell me which jar have to be downloaded to fix this error and from where?

```
    String accessToken = "xxxx";
    FacebookTemplate facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
    //facebook.feedOperations().updateStatus("hello facebook");
    facebook.feedOperations().updateStatus("hey");
```

The error I got is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 org/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType
at pkg.am.ncrb.shot.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

Comment: the error says, NoClassDefFoundError that means either you have not imported the class or the jar is not set in your classpath. Assuming you have imported the class, you can download the jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksoncoreasl182jar.htm

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I added the jar you mentioned above but still  same error is showing

Comment: please share the complete code

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala my code is only that much which is written above

Comment: Add http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl to your dependencies.